# Integration question: $\int \sqrt{x^2-4}\, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am looking for a way to integrate $$\int \sqrt{x^2-4}\  dx $$ using trigonometric substitutions.

All my attempts so far lead to complicated solutions that were uncomputable.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Aaron Maroja's (second) hint, note that

$$\sec\theta\tan^2\theta\ d\theta={\sin^2\theta\ d\theta\over\cos^3\theta}={\sin^2\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta\over\cos^4\theta}={s^2\ ds\over(1-s^2)^2}$$

where $s=\sin\theta$.  Some tedious partial fractions can wrap things up:

$${s^2\over(1-s^2)^2}={A\over1-s}+{B\over(1-s)^2}+{C\over1+s}+{D\over(1+s)^2}$$

Comment: Excellent, indeed is kind of tedious.

Comment: @AaronMaroja, it's a good argument for learning about hyperbolic functions!

Comment: Definitely! You said it all.

Answer (score 3):

For a trigonometric substitution, $ x = 2\sec \theta $ will work if you can integrate certain other trig functions.

Comment: I tried it...it get immensely complicated later on.

Comment: Did you get to (secx)^3 -secx ?

Answer (score 3):

I'll focus on $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{x^2-1}\,\mathrm dx$ for simplicity. This is how I think about this sort of problem when I don't remember the appropriate substitution.

If you suspect that it's useful to use a trigonometric substitution, since the fundamental property $$\forall \theta \in\mathbb R\left((\sin(\theta))^2+(\cos(\theta))^2=1\right)$$ involves only squared numbers, the substitution $x=\varphi(\theta)$ has to be such that $(\varphi(\theta))^2-1$ is a square as opposed to the negative of a square (because of the square root).

So now the goal is to obtain something that looks like $(\varphi(\theta))^2-1$ from $(\sin(\theta))^2+(\cos(\theta))^2=1$.

Clearly something like $(\sin(\theta))^2-1=-(\cos(\theta))^2$ won't help because the RHS is the negative of a square.

The next usual trick with this trigonometric identities is to divide by $\cos$ yielding $(\tan(\theta))^2+1=(\sec(\theta))^2$ from where one gets $(\tan(\theta))^2=(\sec(\theta))^2-1$ which satisfies the criteria above.

Consider the substitution $x=\sec(\theta)$. It will result, after a few calculations, in known antiderivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x = 2 \cosh \theta \Rightarrow dx =  2 \sinh \theta\  d\theta $.

**Edit:** The OP said that he hasn't seen hyperbolic functions just yet. Then what about $x = 2\sec \theta \Rightarrow dx = 2\sec \theta \tan\theta\  d\theta$

So

$$2\int \sqrt{4\sec^2\theta - 4}\sec\theta\tan\theta \ d\theta = 4\int \sec\theta \tan^2\theta d\theta$$

Comment: I would say need substitution: $x = 2\cosh \theta$

Comment: @georg What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong.

Comment: @georg It's all right.

Comment: actually I just substituted $2/cost = x$

Comment: We were told nothing of the use of hyperbolic func here

Comment: I believe I got to this stage as well but was unable to proceed.

Comment: @Bak1139 see Barry Cipra's hint, and try learning hiperbolic functions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution $x = \sec \theta$, we end up with

$$ 4\int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta \,d\theta $$

This can be done using integration by parts

$$ \begin{align} \int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta \,d\theta &= \int \tan \theta \,d(\sec \theta) 
\\&= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec\theta \,d(\tan\theta) 
\\&= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec\theta \,(\tan^2 \theta + 1) \,d\theta 
\\&= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta \,d\theta - \int \sec\theta \,d\theta
\\ 2\int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta \,d\theta &= \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}$$
For reference: [Integral of secant cubed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)