# integration of $\large\int \frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2}$ $ du$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a way to integrate $$\large\int \frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} du$$ without using partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Did you try the substitution $u=\sin\theta?$

Comment: that's a typo, I fixed that.

Comment: Please stop making gratuitous use of size-modifying commands in your future posts, particularly titles. See ["Is there a policy about font size?"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11967).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $f(u) = u$ and  $g(u) = 1-u^2$. Hence,

$$ \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(u) = \frac{u^2+1}{(1-u^2)^2} = \frac{2u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} +  \frac{1-u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} = \frac{2u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-u} + \frac{1}{1+u}\right).$$

Comment: Wrong, the derivate is $\frac{u^2+1}{(1-u^2)^2}$

Comment: @idm, I've edited.

Comment: It's an ad-hoc method and comes from no where (I don't really recommend this method), but it's actually interesting, therefore +1, good job :-)

Comment: @idm, In this case, it is not complicated to find $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. The denominator $(1-u^2)^2$ gives a hint.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} = \frac{u^2-1+1}{(1-u^2)^2} = \frac{u^2-1}{(1-u^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1-u^2}.$$

then see your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099060/partial-fraction-decomposition-on-frac11-u22/1099065#1099065) and you'll get the result,

Comment: And I was going to ask how did you know about the previous post.

Comment: because I answered to the question in his previous post.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I saw it.

Comment: tedious is an understatement for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $u = \sin \theta$.

$$...=\int \frac{\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^4\theta}d\theta = \int \tan^2\theta \sec\theta d\theta$$

Comment: this proceeds with the hyperbolic variant doesn't it?

Comment: I understand! Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095621/integration-question-int-sqrtx2-4-dx/1095626#1095626)question you are trying to solve yet? Or is it a different one?

Comment: ha ha Yes I am...they didn't mention it and left us with not always effective methods to solve problems that are not suited for them.

Comment: I tried to help, I mean, it isn't so difficult to catch up on hyperbolic functions, it's an important tool you should have with you.

Comment: Feel free to ask, maybe on chat. I don't mind answering.

Comment: Haha it's cool mate, I'll do my read-up :)

Comment: Cool, see that you learned a bunch just with one integral, that's why math is incredible!

Answer (score 2):

For the diversity of the solution set, I present an exotic method that works almost exclusively for this integral:

Decompose the integrand as

\begin{align*}
\frac{u^{2}}{(u^{2}-1)^{2}}
&= \frac{1}{u^{2} + u^{-2} - 2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+u^{-2}}{(u-u^{-1})^{2}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1-u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1})^{2} - 4} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+u^{-2}}{(u-u^{-1})^{2}} + \frac{1}{8} \frac{1-u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1}) - 2} - \frac{1}{8} \frac{1-u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1}) + 2}.
\end{align*}

By noting that

$$ \frac{d}{du}(u-u^{-1}) = 1+u^{-2}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\frac{d}{du}(u+u^{-1}) = 1-u^{-2}, $$

it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{u^{2}}{(u^{2}-1)^{2}} \, du
&= - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{u-u^{-1}} + \frac{1}{8} \log \left|(u+u^{-1}) - 2\right| - \frac{1}{8} \log \left|(u+u^{-1}) + 2\right| \\
&= \frac{u}{2(1-u^{2})} + \frac{1}{4} \log \left| \frac{1-u}{1+u} \right|.
\end{align*}

Indeed,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The $u=\tanh t$ substitution is probably the shortest way: $\,\, \mathrm d\,u=\dfrac{\mathrm d\,t}{\cosh t}$, so that

$$ \int\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} \mathrm d\,u=\int \sinh^2t\,\mathrm d\,t=\int\dfrac{\cosh2t-1}2 \mathrm d\,t=\frac14\sinh 2t - \frac t2. $$

Now $\,\,\sinh 2t =\dfrac{2\tanh t}{1-\tanh^2t}=\dfrac{2u}{1-u^2}\,$, so
$$ \int\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} \mathrm d\,u=\frac 12\dfrac{u}{1-u^2}-\frac14\ln\biggl(\frac{1+u}{1-u}\biggr).$$

Comment: I guess $$ \sinh 2t = \frac{2\tanh t}{1-\tanh^{2}t}. $$

Comment: @sos440: Yes, it's the hyperbolic version of the well-known formula for sin 2t. However, I didn't use that formula.

Comment: I mean, you made a sign mistake in your answer…

Comment: @sos440: Thanks for pointing the mistake! I fixed my answer.